# Figuring out problematic field name in a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am selecting fields from a view

```
select 
col1,
col2,
col3,
...
from dbo.vView
```

View is large, it has several million entries and many columns.
When I run above query it returns this error

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

I understand that there is a problem with a data type somewhere. But how to determine problematic field? Is there any simple way to do so?

Comment: Please post your actual query in the view.. The one you posted can not cause an overflow.

Comment: copy out the code from the view and run it... check that line number of that column and debug it. It will probably have a `cast(column as <decimal or numeric or float>)` someColumn

Comment: I know, but i have to load data into table so that you can see it, it seems impossible

Comment: It could be one of the joins that is causing an issue also if you have datatype mismatches. This happens when you have a varchar column storing numerical values and some other value gets in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Focus" on all the columns.
2. Comment the first half of the "focused" columns. Does it produce the error again? If yes, focus now on the non-commented columns. If no, focus now on the commented columns.
3. Repeat step 2 until you find the column responsible. It should take no more than log2(number of columns) steps.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I was just wondering whether there is a functionality like try catch to figure out "wrong" fields, but obviously there is only trial and error method.

Comment: There is a try..catch in sql server, but it would just catch the error you got. It would not provide additional info about the "culprit" column.